# How do I return the IP address of a client who is accessing a Go program in /cgi-bin?

Tags: go, server, ip, cgi

I am trying to simply display the IP address of a client accessing a go program located in our server's /cgi-bin directory. The line in a C program that does the same might look something like:

`printf("Your current IP address is: %s", getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"));`

I am extremely new to Go, with little to no introduction. I imagine it will have something to accessing the http request header, but I am unsure how to do this, and I'm having a hard time understanding the tutorials that I have found.

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you share the code of how this application works, specifically how does a client connect to this go server?

Comment: Programs under cgi-bin are run with caller information in the environment. You should simply get the environment and print it out: os.Getenv

Comment: @Christian I am hesitant to share code because it's for a school assignment. The server is an Apache web server running Ubuntu. All I have now is some printed html.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I am looking at the doc for the os package right now. Is there a default key string for os.Getenv to return the ip?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "os" package I was able to get the client's IP with `os.Getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")`.